# Why is that quotient of homogeneous polynomials (each of same degree) in multivariable case bounded?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, intuition

I am sorry if this isn’t obvious to me. I was doing questions on limits of multivariable functions and encountered such functions.

Is this because both numerator and denominator **decay** at same rate as they approach the origin, so they are bounded?

And what can you say about the limit as it tends to origin in this case?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't think it is true in general that the quotient of homogeneous polynomials is bounded. Why do you say it is? Perhaps there is an additional condition that you have neglected to mention.

Comment: Quotient of homogeneous polynomials each of **same degree**@DavidK

Comment: For example, $x/y$?

Comment: Kind of… yes. Can you tell if I am correct.

Comment: Is $x/y$ bounded? If so, how do you define "bounded" for a function of two variables?

Comment: I mean they both shrink at a same rate so they could be bounded by a number…

Comment: I didn't ask about this particular function, I asked for a definition of what it means for a function of two variables to be bounded. We can't answer the question if we don't know what it means.